# BlurDialogFragmentHelper error if keyboard is open

Tags: java, android, dialog, keyboard, fragment

Thanks in advance, I take time trying to find the solution to this problem. EtsyBlur I am using the library, to display a framgentDialog. Everything works fine, but the main activity is open the keyboard and pulse on the button to open the passage, but it opens the view where the keyboard was not working the drawable blur.

```
 MainActivity{
 description.addTextChangedListener(watcher);


       hide_keyboard(PostActivity.this);
       add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               description.clearFocus();

               PostFragment fragment = PostFragment.newInstance();
               fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

           }
       });[enter image description here][1]void hide_keyboard(Activity activity) {
       InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
       View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
       //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
       if(view == null) {
           view = new View(activity);
       }
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
       inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
   }
```

My DialogFragment class

```
public class PostFragment extends DialogFragment {

private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

private BlurDialogFragmentHelper mHelper;

public static PostFragment newInstance() {
    PostFragment fragment = new PostFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHelper = new BlurDialogFragmentHelper(this);
    mHelper.onCreate();
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_Transparent);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_post, container, false);

    ImageView gallery = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);
    ImageView camera = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    ImageView video = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoButton);
```